# Send datetime field value on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, adobe, livecycle

I did some research and could not find how to fix this. I have a pdf form with a Date/Time field. On run the field gets the current Date/Time value but when I submit the form the date is not sent to the xml document. How do I get the value to be added in the xml document?

EDIT:  **Clarify the submit button**

- Type: Email Submit Button
- Email Address: Myemail@address.com

I do not specify what type of file, it automatically send an .XML document

Comment: Maybe the field is in the list of values that are excluded from export (that's possible in PDF). Maybe it is excluded because it is a value that isn't to be entered by a user, but that can be determined on the server? We'd need to see the PDF to be sure. When you talk about an XML document, it is assumed that you're talking about XFDF. Maybe you want to clarify that.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie  Thank you for helping me, how can I see if the value is excluded? On submit I'm sending an XML document by email, not XFDF.

Comment: There are four ways to submit a form: (1) as an HTML query string, (2) as an FDF file, (3) as an XFDF file, and (4) as a fully filled out PDF. Option (4) is only possible if the end user has Acrobat or if the PDF is Reader enabled. When you say *"I'm sending an XML document by email, not XFDF"*, then no PDF specialist will know what you're talking about. Please clarify: how do you create the XML and why *are you* not including the date? Which option is used to submit the data? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I added some information about the submit button, I could add a screenshot of the properties if you still don't understand

Comment: Do you have an AcroForm or an XFA form? If a mail is sent, I am pretty sure that the PDF contains ECMAScript (aka JavaScript) that is responsible for sending the mail. Please share the JavaScript that is stored in your PDF.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I found how to fix it, see answer below.

Comment: Great. It looks as if you have an XFA form. Changing the script solved the problem. +1 ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to PDF(or XFA) forms so I don't know what is the difference between an AcroForm and an XFA form. I guess this gives me an opportunity to do some research and learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it myself by putting this code:

```
form1.#subform[0].#area[2].DateTimeField1::ready:layout - (FormCalc, client)
$.rawValue = Concat(Num2Date(Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD"), " ", Num2Time(Time(), "HH:MM:SS"))
```

instead of putting current DateTime under the value tab